# How to deny port 1433 access to SQL Server VM while allowing SQL query from Integrated Web App

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I have integrated Azure WebApp to SQL Server VM so that these can communicate via Vnet instead of public internet.

I have denied all TCP port 80 for incomings for security reason. I see that http posts reach successfully from WebApp to VM.

However when I deny all TCP port 1433 for comings, SQL queries stop reaching from Web App to SQL Server VM. I was expecting that integrated VNet would handle this. SQL Server VM have SQL connectivity settings as private(within virtual network)  If I keep 1433 open I can access from my desktop Excel to SQL Server DB, which is security risk in this case.

How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just close 1433 on the network security group to the traffic originating from the internet. That will block external traffic to 1433, but will leave internal intact.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg

Comment: How to define source as internet? Priority: 1010,
Name :SQLServer,
Port 1433,
Protocol: TCP,
Source:  Any,
Destination: Any,
Action: Deny,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-dmz-nsg-asm

Comment: literally what you said, source - internet